# Intellij, how to disable the incredibly slow animation of tool windows

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Is there a way to make intellij a bit snappier and not animate the tool windows?

It's incredibly slow as it is, and not very useful.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Disable the *Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Animate Windows* option in the settings (in IntelliJ IDEA 14). You can also find this option by searching for "animate" in the search box of the settings.

Comment: Thanks, the tool window animation literally locks the UI until complete on Linux Mint (at least on my machine).